# How the Rightmost column of a DataGridView could fill the remaining part of the form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `DataGridView` with 5 columns, with `dock = filled`.

I want the last (rightmost) column's width to fill the remaining right side of the form, when the form is maximized.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Set the `AutoSizeMode` of the (rightmost) column to `Fill`

Comment: And something for last please. My cells are resizable. Now that all my cells are filled, how can I make the width not to be resized below a certain width? Minimum width property doesn't seem to work in this way, so I need to do something different.

Comment: The `MinimumWidth` property of the **column** should work... But please open another question for this instead of 'chatting' in the comments :-)

Comment: I know this is old, but for everyone still looking for an answer for this, you can also set the `AutoSizeColumnsMode` in the DataGridView's properties to `Fill`, no need for additional codes

Answer (score 11):

For anyone who is AutoGenerating their columns (*or even if you're not*), you can call this extension method on your `DataGridView` to resize the last column to `Fill`

**C-Sharp**:

```cs
public static class Utilities
{
    public static void StretchLastColumn(this DataGridView dataGridView)
    {
        var lastColIndex = dataGridView.Columns.Count - 1;
        var lastCol = dataGridView.Columns[lastColIndex];
        lastCol.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
    }
}
```

**Visual Basic:**

```vb
Public Module Utilities

    <Extension()>
    Public Sub StretchLastColumn(ByVal dataGridView As DataGridView)
        Dim lastColIndex = dataGridView.Columns.Count - 1
        Dim lastCol = dataGridView.Columns.Item(lastColIndex)
        lastCol.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill
    End Sub

End Module
```