# How to stretch the last column of gridview

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

What I want to do is when I stretch the last column of the GridView, I want the width of the column and in-turn the width of the grid to extend until I let go of it. Right now, It only stretches to the max width of my screen, then i have to move the scrollbar and then extend the column again. My Column is as follows:-

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn IsGroupable="False"  Header="Mixed" ColumnGroupName="commentGroup" DataMemberBinding="{Binding MixedNotes, Mode=TwoWay}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" MinWidth="200" Width="200" CellStyle="{StaticResource ColumnTooltip}">
                                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.HeaderCellStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="telerik:GridViewHeaderCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource GridViewHeaderCellStyle}">

                                    </Style>
                                </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.HeaderCellStyle>

                            </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
```

Hope I am clear about what I want to do.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: for now i have just a gridview with a columns.. the last column will not resize more than the screen width.

Comment: I want the column width to keep increasing otherwise i keep adjusting the column width only a little at a time. Also i want to drag on the column width and not double click on the width. Double clicking works fine.

Comment: Answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358468/how-the-rightmost-column-of-a-datagridview-could-fill-the-remaining-part-of-the

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think this might work, basically, what you need to do is hook yourself into the events of "stretching of last column started" and "stretching of last column stopped" events.

I am not sure how you do that, but it might be as simple as subscribing to the `MouseDown` and `MouseUp` events on the grip of `GridViewDataColumn`.

Inside of your `MouseDown` and `MouseUp` event handlers, you need to tell that the dragging can happen outside of window too:

[Mouse Move not trigger outside WPF Main Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330452/mouse-move-not-trigger-outside-wpf-main-window)